# Django AWS MySQL Database Issues

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services

I am new to learning Django, and for a project, I need to connect a MySQL Database (using AWS RDS Database) to my app.

I've been following the tutorial, but I've been having an issue with 'RDS_HOSTNAME' not being in os.environ (my RDS_HOSTNAME is specific to my database on AWS).

I don't think this if statement is true:

if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {

       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

But I don't know why (could it be my requirements.txt, which is

`Django==1.9.12
MySQL-python==1.2.3`

(my engine is MySQL 5.6.39)
Or could it be something else like one of my .configs?
Thank you!

Comment: These are environment variables, learn more [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps), it's beter to use `os.environ.get('VARIABLE_NAME')`

Comment: That changed up things, but when I try to use this database somehow, I get a "1045, "Access denied for user 'wsgi'@'xsome_ip_addressx' (using password: YES)"? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to use an old database / third database? this is because the current user set to settings doesn't have access to that db. so create a new user, and grant all privileges to it

Comment: That's probably the issue, what's the best way to do that?